# How to map user data type in cassandra using spring boot data

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-cassandra

I am looking out for some help related with spring boot data using Cassandra database.
 I have following dependencies in my pom.xml.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.10.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.10.3</version>
        </dependency>

The table structure looks like:

@Table(value = "TEST_ORDERS")
public class OrderDTO {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Column(value = "email")
    private String emailId;

    @Column(value = "order_id")
    private int orderId;

    @Column(value = "creation_date")
    private Timestamp creationDate;

    @Column(value = "discount_total")
    private double discountTotal;

    @Column(name = "shipments")
    //This is a UDT type
    private Set<ShippingDetails> shipments;

    //getters and setters here
}

The ShippingDetails object is a UDT with following declartion and i defined as a frozen collection in the cassandra CQL sripts

@UDT(name = "shipping", keyspace = "mc_checkout")
public class ShippingDetails {

    @Field(name = "name")
    private FullName name;

    @Field(name = "quantity_shipped")
    private int quantityShipped;

    @Field(name = "shipping_address")
    private CheckoutAddress shippingAddress; 
    //so on
}

There is a repository created for the basic CRUD operations:
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<OrderDTO, String> {

}

    When i try to invoke findOne API of this repository in my Service class
```

i get below error:
        Cassandra entities must have the @Table, @Persistent or @PrimaryKeyClass Annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data for Apache Cassandra and Datastax' Mapping are two independent tools that try to accomplish the same. Please use either one but don't mix these.

`CrudRepository` is a Spring Data type while `@Field` and `@UDT` are coming from Datastax Mapping.

UDT support for Spring Data for Apache Cassandra is available as of version 1.5, see [reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.usage-annotations). Spring Data for Apache Cassandra 1.5 requires Datastax Java Driver 3.0 or newer.